# IEnumerable View returning null on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `Form` which is filled with some grid like structure with `CheckBoxes` and `DisplayField`.
I want to fetch rows with `Checked CheckBoxes`. **Problem** is i am getting null in `Controller's post` method.

**Models**

```
public class RegisterModuleSelection 
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int mID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Module")]
    public string Module { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Buy")]
    public bool Buy { get; set; }        
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MAK_ERP.Models.RegisterModuleSelection>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register - Modules Selection";}
<h2>
Register - Modules Selection</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterModules", "UserAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterModules", @class = "generalForm" }))
{
<table class="Grid Module">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Module)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration) (Months)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Buy)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.mID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Module)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Duration)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Buy)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="button3" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

**Controller**

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterModules()
    {
        IEnumerable<MAK_ERP.Models.RegisterModuleSelection> model = reg.getModules();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterModules(IEnumerable<Models.RegisterModuleSelection> regMod)
    {
    //regMod is null here
    ...
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML-Code for your form. Have you analyzed the posted paremeters (e.g. with firebug or while debugging) which can help to determine where is the mismatch between your model and posted Parameters?

Comment: So Why you don't use collection of entities in your model?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi i saw that tutorial. if anything is better than this plz answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot bind in this way. `Model binding depends upon how generated html looks like.` In this particular case it should look something like:

```
<input id="item_Buy" type="checkbox" value="true" name="item[0].Buy" checked="checked">
```

If you are okay with some workarounds, you can use a for loop instead of foreach loop where you can add an index to each control name and model binder could bind them properly.

There are some really helpful discussions available, you can check here: [ASP.NET MVC - Insert or Update view with IEnumerable model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781935/690329). And also [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). Another one is: [Modelbinding IEnumerable in ASP.NET MVC POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8832888/690329)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EditorTemplates` to solve the problem.

The accepted answer at [ASP.NET MVC Multiple Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254893/asp-net-mvc-multiple-checkboxes) would help you.

Comment: No, Is not related to Templates.